# Python: for loops and inputs fail when using a list made of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, input

```
class products:
    def __init__(self, id, size, color, price, is_sold):
        self.id = id
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.price = price
        self.is_sold = is_sold
total = 0
product_102 = products(102, 34, 'red', 160, False)
product_104 = products(104, 32, 'blue', 140, False)
all_products = [product_102.id, product_104.id]
print(all_products)
x = input('Enter product id: ')
for each in all_products:
    if each == x:
        all_products.remove(each) 
print(all_products)
```

First of all, I'm very new to python and coding in general and I'm not building something huge just some basic thing here
so, I tried to create a program that contains a list of all my products, when something is sold, I can give the ID of the sold product to input (x) and I start a for loop, if the input equals to one of the product ids, it should get removed but it doesn't happen, it gets completely ignored and nothing gets removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` is a string. Thus, your if-clause becomes something like `"102" == 102` which evaluates to `False`. It should work if you change the line to:

```
x = int(input('Enter product id: '))
```

Please consider to check your input beforehand, as this conversion can lead to an exception if anything else than a decimal string is entered.

Answer (score 0):

All user input in python are of string type.

Say the user entered 104, it's actually '104'.

```
>>> 104 == '104'
False
```

Just change it to an integer.

```
for each in all_products:
if each == int(x):
    all_products.remove(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using this simple construct and make sure to use explicit type conversion to **int** as in Python raw_input from 2.x is the default behavior of input in 3.x.

```
x = int(input('Enter product id: '))
if x in all_products:
    all_products.remove(x) 
    print('removed product:',x)
print(all_products)
```

Or even simpler

```
if x in all_products: all_products.remove(x)
```